# Gmail - one notification for all new messages

Tags: notifications, gmail

I use the new Gmail app on my Galaxy s2.

One notification for each new message s very annoying.

I want the new mail notification to act like on my desktop - a notification on the toolbar that indicates that there is an unread mail.

Can you thing on a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within Gmail while at the inbox screen if you click **Menu** and then **Label Settings** you should then be able to check **notify once** and then you should get notified for every new messages as a group.

Comment: Isn't this backwards? You should *check* `notify once` if you want only one notification for all new messages. The OP is asking for a universal notification, not a notification for each message individually.

Comment: This is the reverse of what the original poster was asking for.